# http-kit dependency issue when updating sente-boot

Tags: clojure, http-kit, sente

Likely something wrong with my updated build.boot file: https://github.com/laforge49/sente-boot/blob/master/build.boot
(Been on the backend too long!)

I've tried changing the version of clojure and clojurescript. Previously I was not finding class RT, so I've made some progress at least.

Here's my dependencies:

```
:dependencies '[
[org.clojure/clojure                       "1.9.0"  :scope "provided"]
[org.clojure/core.async                    "0.4.490"]
[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.562"]
[adzerk/boot-reload        "0.5.1"      :scope "test"]
[adzerk/boot-cljs      "2.0.0" :scope "test"]
[com.taoensso/sente        "1.14.0-RC2"] ; <--- Sente
[com.taoensso/timbre       "4.10.0"]
[http-kit                  "2.3.0"]
[ring                      "1.7.1"]
[ring/ring-defaults        "0.3.2"] ; Includes `ring-anti-forgery`, etc.
[compojure                 "1.6.1"] ; Or routing lib of your choice
[hiccup                    "1.0.5"] ; Optional, just for HTML
[com.cognitect/transit-clj  "0.8.313"]
[com.cognitect/transit-cljs "0.8.256"]
[onetom/boot-lein-generate "0.1.3"]]
```

I get this error:

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: clojure/lang/IFn
data: {:file "org\\httpkit\\server.clj", :line 66}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/IFn
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.lang.IFn
...
clojure.core/load/fn                          core.clj: 6007
clojure.core/load/invokeStatic                          core.clj: 6006
clojure.core/load                          core.clj: 5990
...
```

Comment: It looks like you are using boot - have you tried `boot show -d`, or looked at boot pedantic (ex =, https://corfield.org/blog/2016/06/17/more-boot/ )?

Comment: boot show -d blows up with the same error in httpkit. Pedantic looks quite interesting. As well as excluding clojure. As far as I can tell, excluding clojure was no help. I'll focus then on using Pedantic, though it will likely be a few days till I get back to it. But this feels right. :-) --Let you know how it works out. Thanks!